# POST requests gives 405 error on Python flask server

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to do a POST request using python requests and flask, however the server gives a 405 error.

Client:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith'}

url = 'http://localhost:5000/order'

r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
```

Server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/order', method='POST')
   def getjson():
       print('hello')
```

When I try this code on the client side it works fine:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/order')
print(r.status_code)
```

Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: I think you need `@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])`

Answer (score 1):

`Error 405 Method Not Allowed` indicates that the request from client is not a valid request format. Details of 405 error can be found in [Mozilla's documentation on HTTP 405 error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).

I have updated the typo in server Python code. Also updated the client code to send the JSON properly.

Server:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
def getjson():
    content = request.json
    return jsonify(content)
```

Client:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith'}
url = 'http://localhost:5000/order'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Client output:

```
200
{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith'}
```